# Explanation of action creator and extraction of types from them

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm putting together a little app using typescript, react and redux, and I came across this little thing called an action creator.

The code for the action creator class is as following, original creator, and props goes to github@plotrwitek;

```
export class ActionCreator<T, P> {
  readonly type: T;
  readonly payload: P;

  constructor(type: T) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  create = (payload: P) => ({
    type: this.type,
    payload
  });
}
```

Now, in the reducer, I'm instantiating these action creators, and extracting the different types as following;

```
export const ActionCreators = {
  TestAction: new ActionCreator<'TestAction', string>('TestAction'),
};
```

The reason I'm using `Partial<...>` under is because it would complain about a missing `create` property, which is present on the class, but not on what is returned from the `create` method.

```
export type Action = Partial<typeof ActionCreators[keyof typeof ActionCreators]>;
```

What I'm wondering is the following; could someone please provide an explanatin as to how the `typeof ...[keyof typeof ...]` works, and if possible; provide an alternative solution to this that accounts for the missing `create` property - a type that only contains the possible returns from the `create` method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tl;dr* The resulting type of `typeof SomeObject[keyof typeof SomeObject]` will be [the union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of `SomeObject`'s value types. In your example `Partial<ActionCreator<"TestAction", string>>`. It basically is a list of all existing actions.

---

Here is an explanation of the steps:

1. `typeof ActionCreators`: Tells TS to use the type of the const
2. `keyof (1)`: Will give you the union type all the keys of `ActionCreators`. In your case it's only one: `TestAction`
3. `typeof ActionCreators[(2)]` will give you the value of all keys. It more or less is "iterating" over the object and "returning" its values types.

Which version of TypeScript do you use? I do not get an error when I remove the `Partial` (using TS 2.6.2).

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the explanation! I'm using 2.7.1. The issue occured when I tried to create an action like `const testAction: Action = { type: 'TestAction', payload: 'random string' };`. I'm on my mobile now, but I can update with more information when I get home.

Comment: Alright, I have a test right now, which imports the Actions, and attempts to create an action as following: 
`const action: Action = ActionCreators.TestAction.create('test value');`
Typescript then gives this error: `Type '{ type: "TestAction"; payload: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ActionCreator<"TestAction", string>'.
  Property 'create' is missing in type '{ type: "TestAction"; payload: string; }'.`

Comment: That's kinda hard to read. Can you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or something for testing purposes?

Comment: Of course; https://codesandbox.io/s/7zqzrjjv3x. The code discussed is from the repository https://github.com/FredrikAugust/typescript-react-boilerplate with the files discussed being `test/defaultReducer.test.ts`, `src/actions/action-creator.ts` and `src/reducers/reducer.ts`.

Comment: I am not sure that this is an issue with the above code, since codesandbox does not show any errors (hovering over create actually shows the correct typings also). I copy/pasted the code in my editor and everything worked fine there too. Type inference also works. I created another action that only accepts a `number` instead of a `string` and typescript successfully warned me.

Comment: That is very, very odd. Could it be an issue with the typescript version? Or perhaps Visual Studio Code?

I can try to change the version and see if the error still persists.